# How to check if no string exists between two given words?

Tags: python, string

I need to check that given any two words, if there exists a string between them or nothing.

For example I have a sentence `Hey how are you?`. In this I need to check any string exists between two words `Hey` and `how`. This is what I do currently

```
s = "hey how are you?"
substring1 = 'hey'
substring2 = 'how'
my_string = s[(s.index(substring1)+len(substring1)):s.index(substring2)]
if " " in my_string:
    print("no string found!")
```

Here I pick anything that is in between the two words and check if it is an empty space. It seems to work but there is a problem. If I add a string in between and put spaces around it something like `"hey there how are you?"`, it still says no string found.

I need to be sure that if absolutely nothing exists between the two words, only then I output the message. How can I do it?

Comment: `if substring1 + substring2 in s: print("nothing inbetween")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only spaces are allowed between words, you could split on space and check if the indices of `"hey"` and `"end"` are contiguous:

```
s = "hey how are you?"

start = "hey"
end = "how"

words = s.split()

if abs(words.index(end) - words.index(start)) > 1:
    print("something")
else:
    print("nothing")
```

**Output**

```
nothing
```

Comment: nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking advantage of pythons inbuilt regular expression lib.

The regex library can provide the position of the matched string, in only a few lines.

Regular expressions are extremely useful for pattern matching and extracting information from the text by searching for one or more matches of a specific search pattern

```
import re
print(re.match("hey how", "hey how are you?"))
print(re.match("hey how", "hey are you ok?"))
```

**output**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='hey how'>
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach along the lines of the comment from [@L3viathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016216/l3viathan). This would allow some additional flexibility with different word separators, punctuation, etc.

```
test1 = 'hey how are you?'
test2 = 'ho hey and how'

match = 'hey how'

def phrase_match(s, m):
    if m in s.lower():
        return f'found "{m}" in "{s}"'
    return f'"{m}" not found in "{s}"'

print(phrase_match(test1, match))
# found "hey how" in "hey how are you?"

print(phrase_match(test2, match))
# "hey how" not found in "ho hey and how"
```